# Question related to how polyfit and poly1d funciton works

Tags: python

I have a dataframe which I apply the following function but I am not sure exactly what is going on

```
def fit(data):

    global p, z, y

    y = data.values
    x = np.arange(0, len(y)) + 1
    z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    p = np.poly1d(z)

    print(y)
    print(z)
    print(p)

    return p(x)
```

As an extract the variables have the following values:

```
y = [0.45054945 0.77391829 0.93503301 0.95208799 0.97273485 0.9763856
     0.98 0.99297733 0.99444444 0.99565217 0.99589071 0.99745743 
     0.99819519]

z = [0.02658079 0.73819032]

p = 0.02658 x + 0.7382
```

From this I understand that the data is taken in the long list and a line is fitted. The part I don't understand is the `[0.02658079 0.73819032]`. Where do these values come from?

I have looked at this https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html but I am missing something in where `[0.02658079 0.73819032]` comes from.

Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

Sandy

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I now know what is happening now.

The p values are coefficients of the fitted line.